# Time frame to pass the MCPD Web Developer .NET 4

Tags: .net, web

I have 24 months experience develping .NET C# client/server apps in my profession as Soft developer.

Now starting in a new company I have a probation time of 6 months. My new employeer wants to give me 6 month of time to get the MCPD Web Developer 4. If I understood the Microsoft website correctly I have to pass FOUR exams those are:

```
Web Developer 4 on Visual Studio 2010


Exam number

MCTS prerequisite: TS: Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Exam 70-515

MCTS prerequisite: TS: Windows Communication Foundation Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Exam 70-513

MCTS prerequisite: TS: Accessing Data with Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Exam 70-516

MCPD requirement: PRO: Designing and Developing Web Applications Using Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Exam 70-519
```

Can this be achieved at all within 6 months? I think thats ridiculous.

What do you think what is the best way to achieve this?

Even more I would like to hear your experience how you have done the

"MCPD Web Developer 4"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can share my experience. I'm an MCPD Windows Developer (2.0), an MCT and working on my MCPD 4.0 Windows.

You are required to write the 4 exams. Two of them are common between Windows and Web Developer certifications. (70-513, 70-516)

I've written 70-511 and my experience with it was the same as my experience with the 2.0 exam track.

I took approx. 2 weeks per exam to prep and then write the exams. During the 2 weeks, I read the entire MS Press Exam preparation book for the exam I was after. I would write MeasureUp practice exams during the 2nd week to start targeting what I was going to have to re-read or practice up on more.  All in, I probably take 60-80 hours or so to prep for each exam, including the time required to write the exam which usually takes 4 hrs from getting in the door to getting back to work.

One thing I would caution though is that all of the MS Press Exam guides have not been published and won't be for available anytime soon.

- [70-515 - Available Now](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627401)
- [70-516 - June 21, 2011](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627398)
- 70-513 (not listed on Amazon)
- [70-519 - July, 2011](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735657262)

Also, the Microsoft Official Curriculum courses that may contribute to learning and passing these exams are for the most part not ready either.

There are [learning guides that you can use](http://learning.microsoft.com/Manager/Catalog.aspx?cats=%7Bd4e8e42c-3d5a-4a6e-915d-d99556a49bd7%7D) to start learning. I haven't started one yet, but plan to in the near future.

I hope all of this information helps. I think you've got a challenging road ahead, but it is doable. I do hope your employer plans to give you support like books, practice exams and time to practice all of this stuff.

Also, you can purchase [exam voucher certification packs](http://www.prometric.com/microsoft/certpacks) that give you a discount on the cost of exams and free second shots are included. The second shots are specific to each exam and you don't get "x second shots" to the any of the exams in the pack. And if you do need to take advantage of a second shot, make sure you use that second shot properly and don't just re-use the exam pack voucher code. You'll use up your 4-5 vouchers by accident.

Comment: +1, some very useful links in there. I'm not sure the MS Pres Exam guides are actually that good, I found the Cram guides better.

Comment: I will start with the 515 then go on with the others where the books are available. I have less experience in WCF,ASP so it will be a hard time. Sit down read and do the samples practically thats prolly the best way. Thanks for your links, my employeer pay all the exams even if I fail.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done any MCPD exams, but I did their predecessors (MCSD) a few years ago. There were 5 of those, and I completed them all in about 8 or 9 months, having no previous .Net, or even Microsoft, experience. I would typically take 1 weekend and a day off work to work through the books and it really wasn't too hard. Obviously I didn't spend the whole 8 months on the exams, I was working full time anyway. I guess each exam took about 20 hours prep at the most.

I'm assuming the MCPD exams are a pretty similar level to the old MCSD, if so I don't think it would be too hard to get them done in 6 months given you have 2 years experience.